# Load testing for WCF services

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio, load-testing

I want to do Load Testing for few WCF services. My services are hosted in IIS.

I have VS 2008/10/12 all professional versions.

So I went for this http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/ , and it seems it needs VS ultimate edition to work.

Is there any free tool to do Load testing for WCF services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) and [WcfStorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/) are two tools I use for unit and load testing of my services.

Comment: They both have perfectly free versions. I've used them for years.

Comment: The link is saying ...`Download trial version`